# How to get the proxy service information deployed on wso2 esb

Tags: wso2, esb

How to get the proxy service information deployed on wso2 esb ,like the url 、 name 、 wsdl ?
I try to access these information via service of esb on this url:https://    :8243/services/ProxyServiceAdmin.ProxyServiceAdminHttpsSoap11Endpoint
,but the esb make some errors:

[2013-11-15 13:32:28,205] ERROR - AuthenticationHandler
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.module.handler.AuthenticationHandler.invalidateSession(AuthenticationHandler.java:202)
        at org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.module.handler.AuthenticationHandler.isAuthenticated(AuthenticationHandler.java:162)
        at org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.module.handler.AuthenticationHandler.authenticate(AuthenticationHandler.java:83)
        at org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.module.handler.AuthenticationHandler.invoke(AuthenticationHandler.java:55)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:261)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:167)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:404)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:184)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
[2013-11-15 13:32:28,206] ERROR - AxisEngine Authentication failure
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Authentication failure
        at org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.module.handler.AuthenticationHandler.authenticate(AuthenticationHandler.java:110)
        at org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.module.handler.AuthenticationHandler.invoke(AuthenticationHandler.java:55)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:261)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:167)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:404)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:184)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
[2013-11-15 13:32:28,206] ERROR - ServerWorker Error processing POST request for : /services/ProxyServiceAdmin.ProxyServiceAdminHttpsSoap11Endpoint
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Authentication failure
        at org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.module.handler.AuthenticationHandler.authenticate(AuthenticationHandler.java:110)
        at org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.module.handler.AuthenticationHandler.invoke(AuthenticationHandler.java:55)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:261)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:167)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:404)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:184)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)

Answer (score 0):

try this url:
https ://NAMEOFSERVER:8280 or your port/Services/NameOfService?wsdl
and you can login to your esb and in main-services-list
right click on wsdl1.1 your service and click copy link adress and paste in your browser